# understanding the relationship between static and weak reference

Tags: java, android

I was going through [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_weakhashmap_class.htm) and I decide to remove the static from this line of code:

```
private static Map map;
```

the code did not give any errors..  , however the weak reference did not get removed from the hashmap. Can you tell me why map must be static in order for weak reference to work ?

Comment: What do you mean by weak reference ?

Comment: A `Map` is not `static`. A variable is `static`. `Can you tell me why map must be static in order for weak reference to work ?` It doesn't.

Comment: What let you think it don't work?

Comment: `understanding the relationship between static and weak reference` - there is none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply remove `static` in

```
private static Map map;
```

your code won't compile, because `non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context`, which is the `main` method in this tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Static means there's only one instance of that variable that every instance of that class shares.  Removing the static would mean that there are more of those maps around (one per instance of the class) and that those instances wouldn't have the same data.

Weak references are totally different.  They are ways to keep a reference around but still let a variable be garbage collected if nobody else needs it.  The two concepts have nothing to do with each other.